# Why do I need an extra element in AWS CloudFormation for interpolating variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, string-interpolation

I am trying to pass user data to an EC2 instance created in Cloudformation, using the following:

```
      UserData: !Base64
        'Fn::Join':
          - ''
          - - |
              #!/bin/bash -xe
              echo '
            - !Ref 'someVar'
            - |
              ' > /tmp/some-content
```

which works. Here is the expanded user data (btw, I also don't know why there is a new line after `echo '` but that is not the main question):

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
echo '
some string passed as parameter' > /tmp/some-content
```

But if I remove the `-` from the !Ref part, it treats !Ref as a string:

```
      UserData: !Base64
        'Fn::Join':
          - ''
          - - |
              #!/bin/bash -xe
              echo '
              !Ref 'License'
              ' > /tmp/some-content
```

Here is the expanded user data.

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
echo '
!Ref 'someVar'
' > /tmp/some-content
```

Why is this happening? Is this a cloudformation internal thing, that expands !Ref variables only if they are alone as an element in a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't be it just easier to do this this way:

```
  UserData: 
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe 
          echo "${someVar}" > /tmp/some-content
```

Basically there is no need to use `Join` and suffer. use `!Sub |` which is much less painful to work with. The code is much more readable and much easier to manage.